# Is this scenario a combinaton or a permutation?

Tags: permutations, combinations

Scenario:

I have a program that draws two flowers (out of eight possible flowers) on a screen - one after the other - and then terminates.

If I wanted to work out the possible number of flowers drawn by the program without repeats, would I use the formula for combinations or permutations?

Answer (score 0):

A 'combination' is when the order **doesn't matter**, but 'permutation' is when the order **does matter**.

For example, if you wanted to choose $2$ fruits in the list {apple, orange, banana, pear, grape}, that would be a combination, because it doesn't matter if you pick {apple, banana} or {banana, apple}. However, if you had a password that uses the digits '$1$', '$2$' and '$3$', the password '$123$' is different from '$213$', because every digit has to be in the right place.

In your scenario, does it matter if you choose {red flower, yellow flower} or {yellow flower, red flower}? Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: Yes, it does matter as the terminal would print it in a different order. Thus, it must be a permutation. Thanks for your help.